# IE driver browser not working using JSR223 sampler - jmeter

Tags: performance, selenium-webdriver, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I am using JSR223 Sampler to use IE browser and run some validation on UI.

code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
File file = new File("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEDriverServe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

//System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\Users\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.3\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin\IEDriverServer");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities)
def wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
driver.get('https://google.com/');
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//input[@name='q']")));
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

error :
2020-10-08 11:43:08,472 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2020-10-08 11:43:08,472 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: IE 1-1
2020-10-08 11:43:08,479 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script iecONFIG, message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script23.groovy: 8: Unexpected input: '"webdriver.ie.driver","' @ line 8, column 44.
ew File("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\Progra
^

1 error

javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script23.groovy: 8: Unexpected input: '"webdriver.ie.driver","' @ line 8, column 44.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your script, i.e.:

1. `File file = new File("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEDriverServe");` this constructor doesn't make sense, see [File javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for possible options
2. You declare `WebDriver driver` twice, on 2nd occurrence your script will fail
3. You need to add `.exe` to `IEDriverServer`

Suggested code change:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", 'c:/full/path/to/IEDriverServer.exe');

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities)
def wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
driver.get('https://google.com/');
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//input[@name='q']")));
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

More information: [Internet Explorer Driver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

Is there any specific reason for not using [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) with [InternetExplorer Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InternetExplorerConfig/)? It will be way more easy given you're not too familiar with Selenium and JMeter